# Vertically fill a parent flex-box container with 3 items each at 33% of height

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

What I currently have using Tailwind (see [this playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XxIyrbS9Ka))

```html
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col items-center space-y-6">
  <div class="h-1/3">X</div>
  <div class="h-1/3">X</div>
  <div class="h-1/3">X</div>
</div>
```

What I like is that each of the 3 items take 33% (minus the y-spacing) of the `h-screen` container.

What happens there is that the `h-screen` container is larger than the height of the screen so there's a scroll, you can see that in the playground I've added.

There is a parent around that container with `py-6`. I initially thought that was the problem, but if I do this:

```html
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col items-center space-y-6">
  <div class="">X</div>
</div>
```

With that same `py-6` parent around it, it works as expected and there's no scroll.

Comment: Do you need three elements have same height while your app has no scroll no matter what parent's paddings are? https://play.tailwindcss.com/CASV8MyTuh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other classes like `flex-1` to expand your flex-child and mind margins, also `flex-col` on the parent holding a single child is not necessary., `h-screen` on the child is also not necessary, the parent is already a sized flexbox and will fill it up:

possible example :

```
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex  justify-center">
  <div class=" flex flex-col items-center space-y-6">
    <div class="flex-1 bg-red-500">X</div>
    <div class="flex-1 bg-green-500">X</div>
    <div class="flex-1 bg-yellow-500">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/VCTmCjUAQA

make it 2 children, it will be 50% minus margins, four : 25% minus margins and so on. flex do the math itself ;)